# cheapo CCFL LCD keeps colour-drifting - what is the cause?

Tags: glcd, colour, ccfl

My display's (Phillips 231E) white point drifts continiously. Once I have created profile for it it will be fine for some time but then it will shift slightly or badly.

For example: in some cases I can barely reach 115 cd/m^2 at desirable colour temperature (D65) but ATM it goes all up to 140 at same settings along with white point shift. The only thing which changed since last setup/profiling is room temperature - it dropped by three K degrees or so.

I surely know that colour depends on the temperature of backlight source (both for LED and CCFL) and I now that I should let the LCD warm up before colour-critical usage.

Will removing the cover from backlight source which makes it heat more help me to eliminate white point drifting? (Yes, I will do it if it is expected to solve the problem at least partially and yes, I know what I am doing)

Is there some common type of dependency of luminance on T_amb to confirm my suggestion? I checked out the datasheets which I had but there is no graph saying how luminance depends on temperature.

The power line potential is roughly 220V and does not drift significantly.

P.S. Let me know if I should direct my question elsewhere. I thought that SU is not right place for it.

Comment: Sounds like a dodgy CCFL or inverter to me.

Comment: LCDs themselves are also highly temperature dependent - somewhere around 50C they typically go completely black. Is your environment abnormally warm?

Comment: I think you said it all in the title "cheapo CCFL LCD". If you really know what you are doing then purchase a product with specifications that meet your requirements!!

Comment: @brian-drummond: no, not at all. Temperatures of my room are all inside 17 to 21 C range. Also, the previous drop of brightness (from 130 to 115) did not follow huge temperature increase.

Comment: @michael-karas: I have never met mention of drifting in any specifications or monitors I have looked at. Could you enlighten me?

Comment: @EuriPinhollow - I cannot provide you the specifications that you apparently need to meet your requirements. If you have performance requirements for a product it is really up to you research and find what you need. That may mean interfacing with your suppliers and/or manufacturers. My main point in posting my first comment is that when "cheapo" is in the equation you generally take what you get. Buying according to some specific level of specifications rarely fits the "cheapo" scenario.

Comment: @michael-karas: I am more of a very technically minded and advanced consumer than of electronical engineer (this is why I asked whether question is suitable here). I had no chance of choosing the display which I currently use (to be exact: I could choose from this one and one significantly worse). You make wrong implications about my case.

Comment: This does actually appear to be off-topic.  This is asking about the performance of a piece of consumer electronics rather than about electronic design.  I'm sorry I can't recommend a better home for this question.

Comment: @jre: while the question does not discuss electronic design it discusses technical parameters of CCFL lamps used for backlight and dependency of luminance on the T_amb.

Comment: @ignacio-vazquez-abrams: do you mean "spoiled and should be replaced"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens so that cooling was really the only issue of this LCD monitor. CCFL lamps are located in the top and the bottom of the case and got no ventilation at all (except that through actual LCD screen). The ventilation cooled the controlling circuits only.

[image]

This graph from [this document](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an65fa.pdf) shows the reason for brightness and tint drift. An ambient temperature change is expected to give roughly the same temperature change of a cased component. However, if the CCFL is too heated, the temperature change will affect the brightness (along with tint aka white point) more dramatically. This is why moderate ambient temperature change gave such a big shift.

I took the casing off and now the monitor case looks like bare metal. I built new profile a week ago and had no need in profiling again: the brightness and white point stay inside recommended range (+- 1% for brightness) very well after warmup (as expected).